# Access a private function from a script

Tags: matlab

I have a *private* function that I need to call from a MATLAB script (not a function).

Apparently, you can only access a private function from another function, but not from a script. You can read about this [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html).

In order to overcome this problem I simply included a function header with no input and output arguments.

Like this:

```
function myFunction()
% original script
% call private function here
end
```

This solved the problem, but why this small change makes such a big difference?

Comment: From the documentation: `Although you cannot call the private function from the command line or from functions outside the parent of the private folder`. A script is no different from operating from the command line.

Comment: @RobertStettler a script is not an emulation of anything. It's executing the commands in the workspace of the caller. If you're F5-ing the script, this is the base MATLAB workspace.

Comment: @excaza - unless you're F5-ing while debugging something else and happen to be in a different workspace :)

Comment: @RobertStettler - an important difference between command line and a file is **performance** (see JIT) - scripts are usually computationally superior due to optimizations applied to their contents during runtime, assuming the script is run "as-is" and not executed line-by-line or using F9.

Comment: @Dev-iL `scripts are usually computationally superior`? Citation needed. Scripts in MATLAB have a specific definition.

Comment: @excaza what **I** meant by "_script_" is anything that you put inside an `.m` file (this differs from the [definition of TMW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html)). To clarify: _execute file **GOOD**; execute separate commands in command line **BAD**_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you linked already contains the relevant information:

> Private functions are useful when you want to limit the scope of a function. You designate a function as private by storing it in a subfolder with the name private. Then, the function is available only to functions in the folder immediately above the private subfolder, **or to scripts called by the functions that reside in the parent folder.**

A script does not have it's own scope/workspace , it inherits the scope/workspace of the caller. In your case (assuming you call it directly from the console) it is the base workspace where the function is not visible.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading more about the topic [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html). I'm still trying to digest this. I don't understand why the private file is not visible to the script, since the script is residing on the parent folder. To me the scope/workspace idea sounds like it would only affect to the local variables of a function, but not files.

Comment: The scope addresses variables and functions, in matlab you have a mixed scope for variables and functions. Some languages separate that, using a different syntax for variable indexing and function calls.

Comment: Understood. One last question: assuming that I run independent scripts and functions that reside inside a folder on my computer desktop, the scope for a script would be the base workspace, and for a function it would be the desktop folder. Is this affirmation correct?

Comment: You are mixing up the terminology, but I think you understood it now.